# why is writeline not stopping at /r?

Tags: c#

I am using C# Microsoft visual studio professional 2013. 
I am writing :

```
[0] 0 '\0'  char
[1] 1 ''    char
[2] 0 '\0'  char
[3] 0 '\0'  char
[4] 0 '\0'  char
[5] 8 '\b'  char
[6] 1 ''    char
[7] 3 ''    char
[8] 0 '\0'  char
[9] 0 '\0'  char
[10]    65535 '.'   char
[11]    65534 ''    char
[12]    0 '\0'  char
[13]    0 '\0'  char
[14]    13 '\r' char
```

but my end program is only seeing 
0 1 0 0 0 8 1 3 0 
it is not seeing the whole message.  I was writing to a program called Modbus Master. That send my code a request for data and my code replies back. I am getting the full message from Modbus Master, but it is not getting the full massage back from my code.

here is my code :

```
 void Listener_function()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

        TcpListener listener = null;
        try
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(Moxa_IPtxt.Text), Convert.ToInt16(modemPorttxt.Text));
            listener.Start();
            // ErrorBox.Text = " EchoServer started ... /n";
            MessageBox.Show(" waiting for incoming client connections.../n /r");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            MessageBox.Show(" Accepted new client coneection ...");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            while (true)
            {

                string s = string.Empty;
                char[] temp = new char[12];
                int s1 = reader.Read(temp, 0, 12);
                int Registers_number = (((int)temp[10] << 8) + (int)temp[11]);
                int Message_Size = (Registers_number * 2) + 8;
                char[] Message3 = new char[Message_Size];
                TCPProcessing(temp, Message3);
                if (writeData == true) { 
                writer.Write(Message3);
                writer.Flush();
            }
              /*  reader.Close();
                writer.Close();
                client.Close();  */
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            //ErrorBox.Text = e.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.Stop();
            }

        }
    }
```

message 3 is a  global array of size 30.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tag = new List<Tag>();
        Tagcall = new List<tagcall>();
        Message3 = new char[30]; }
```

why is writeline not stopping at /r?

Comment: why should it stop at /r?

Comment: because /r is the end of a string ... right ? if that is not right, than how do I tell it to stop? I do not know  size of the return message until after I get the request from Modbus master.

Comment: try to send esc

Comment: `because /r is the end of a string ... right ?` No it is just another char (BTW:  I guess you mean `\r`)

Comment: Exactly, it isn't the end of a string, it's called return carriage

Comment: yes I meant '\r'

Comment: Should you be using char in the Modbus comms - this is a 2byte value (hence values of 65535/65534)? In Modbus serial comms byte arrays are used. See tutorial here  : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXXJZpbkL1I&list=PLRCEJ0bGSS1aTbj9wjsC5HmlV_vKOWPR4

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems with your code:

- first you tell us you are writing 15 byte (first snippet), but you are only trying to read 12 at a time(`char[] temp = new char[12];`)
- `int s1 = reader.Read(temp, 0, 12);` while you are saving the number of read bytes you are never checking if you have read enough data to start processing it

And lastly [Streamwriter.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebb1kw70(v=vs.110).aspx) writes until the [TextWriter.CoreNewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.corenewline(v=vs.110).aspx) character is encountered. if that's `\r` for your system it will correctly stop. If you want to write all or your char[] you should use [StreamWriter.Write(char[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/275y93ck(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The Modbus Master program will only every send 12 bytes and the Modbus Master program starts the communication

Comment: you still should check is `s1 == 12`. else you will have to keep reading

Comment: I have a check in TCPProcessing(temp);  beside that part is working .. it is the writing back part that is not ... I have used the debugger and message has the values i am putting in them, but it is not stopping at the right place

Comment: -Marco Salerno  I tried putting  esc  at the end but it did not help

Comment: If you want to make sure a that the whole array is sent you should use the appropriate method. See the edit

Comment: DawnKeeper- I changed the code to write and I size message before i send it, but it is still stop at the same spot

Comment: ok the debugger says that Message3 has this : [0] 0 '\0' char
  [1] 3 '' char
  [2] 0 '\0' char
  [3] 0 '\0' char
  [4] 0 '\0' char
  [5] 8 '\b' char
  [6] 1 '' char
  [7] 3 '' char
  [8] 0 '\0' char
  [9] 0 '\0' char
  [10] 65535 '.' char
  [11] 65534 '' char
  [12] 0 '\0' char
  [13] 0 '\0' char

Comment: so it should be sending the full message out for writer.Write(Message3) but it is not, Modbus master only getting  0 3 0 0 0 8 1 3 0

Comment: What is the message size the master expects?

Comment: It is expecting 14 bytes